# SQL Script run on this server but don't on other server

Tags: sql-server, web-services, sql-server-2012

I have an weird issue with SQL Server. I have a small trigger that makes a request to a web service on update.

I have tested that code, it worked fine.

But when I move that code to another SQL Server machine, it does not run. No error are raised.

**Update**: if I call a "Get" request, it's ok. With "Post" request, that SQL Server can't handle it. Both servers run on Windows 2012

My code to call request:

```
DECLARE @dbName NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @wsAction NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @secret NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @url NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @idArray NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @triggerTime DATETIME

SET @dbName = 'dbname' + '/notification/object'
SET @secret = 'a key'
SET @url   = 'https://myserver/api/1.0.0/customer/databaseName='
SET @idArray = '1,2,3'
SET @wsAction = '"action": "modify"'

IF(@idArray <> '')
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Object INT;
        DECLARE @body NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @url = @url + @dbName;
    SET @body = '{"ids": [' + @idArray + '], ' + @wsAction +'}'

    EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setOption', null, 2, 13056 -- by pass ssl
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'post', @url,'false'
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'secret', @secret
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate'
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send', NULL, @body
    Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000);
    Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT
    Select @ResponseText
    EXEC sp_OADestroy @Object
END
```

The "GET" request I test:

```
Declare @Object as Int;
Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000);

Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get',
                                                          'http://www.webservicex.com/stockquote.asmx/GetQuote?symbol=MSFT', --Your Web Service Url (invoked)
                                                          'false'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT

Select @ResponseText


Exec sp_OADestroy @Object
```

Comment: What happens? Literally nothing? Can you show the trigger?

Comment: @scsimon: I have added the code

Comment: Same server versions? Same DB names? Just asking what others will want to know. At first pass I don't see the issue but will look deeper.

Comment: "SQL Server 11.0.5623" - the one that can't run the "Post" request
Is there any firewall policy or sql configuration that block the "Post" method?

Comment: Calling an **external service** in a trigger is a bad idea - you should keep your trigger (if you have any at all) very **lean and small** - do **not** do any heavy lifting, extensive processing, or calling of external services inside the trigger.... this delays your transaction from committing (or rolling back) until the service call has completed - and that can lead to very poor performance of your main application. You should **decouple** these two things - trigger and web service call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem
A known bug with "msxml3.dll":
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2968741
And this link helps me alot:
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/Miscellaneous/30867/
To get the error information